# Trouble with Google charts, queries and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a very simple website consisting of a Google bubble chart overlaid on a background image. The bubble chart is supposed to be generated based on data from a set of Google spreadsheets, and the user can select, through a simple text form, the names of the data points that are to be published. In the code below I have obfuscated the spreadsheet URL, because I don't want to make the data public yet (note however that the viewing privileges of the document are set to public, as required).

The code doesn't work, as no chart is drawn. Obviously there is something fishy going on, because there is never an alert from the `collectData` method, which handles the query response.

Also, initially I didn't have the `draw` method and its code was instead in the `sendAndDraw` method, *sans* the `setTimeout`. In that version, I got a `Data table not found` error on the webpage, but again, the `collectData` method didn't seem to be called, as it didn't raise an error.

Any suggestions as to what might be the issue? I should add that I am completely new to both javascript and Google developers tools.

**EDIT**: Following kfa's comment, the form was changed to include a post method. Now I get the `Data Table not defined problem once again`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#container{
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
#background{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
#bubbleChart{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
</style>
<title>gRNA</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages' : ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {initialize()});

var dataSourceUrls = [
   'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/foo/edit#gid=0&headers=1'
];
var nSheets = dataSourceUrls.length;
var query;
var bubbleDataArray = [];
var bubbleData;

function initialize() {
  //Currently not doing anything here
}

//Takes a list of names as a comma separated list.
function sendQueries(nameString) {
   var queryString = generateQuery(nameString);
   for(i = 0; i < nSheets; i++) {
      query = new google.visualization.Query(dataSourceUrls[i]);
      query.setQuery(queryString);
      query.send(collectData);
      query.abort();
   }
}

//Generates the query string for the selected names.
function generateQuery(nameString) {
   nameString = nameString.split(",");
   var nNames = nameString.length;
   var queryString = [];
   queryString.push("select F, D, E, B ");
   queryString.push("where F matches ");
   queryString.push(nameString[0]);
   for(i = 1; i < nNames; i++) {
      queryString.push("or ");
      queryString.push(nameString[i]);
   }
   return queryString.join("");
}

//Collect and manage the query responses.
function collectData(response) {
   alert('Hi!');
   if(response.isError()) {
      alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' +
          response.getDetailedMessage());
      return;
   }
   var data = response.getDataTable();
   if(data.getNumberOfRows() > 0) {
      bubbleDataArray.push(data);
   }
}

function sendAndDraw(nameString) {
   bubbleDataArray = [];
   sendQueries(nameString);
   setTimeout(draw,2000);
}

function draw() {
   bubbleData = bubbleDataArray[0];
   var nTables = bubbleDataArray.length;
   for(i = 1; i < nTables; i++) {
      bubbleData = google.visualization.data.join(bubbleData,
          bubbleDataArray[i], 'full', [[0,0]],
          [1,2,3], [1,2,3]);
   }
   var container = document.getElementById('bubbleChart');
   var bubbleChart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(container);
   var options = {
     'backgroundColor':'transparent'   
   }

   bubbleChart.draw(bubbleData,options);
 }

 function plot() {
   sendAndDraw(document.getElementById('nameSel').value);
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<form onsubmit="plot(); return false;" method="post">
<input type="text" id="nameSel"/>
<input type="submit" value="Plot"/>
</form>

<br />
<div id="container">
    <div id="background"></div>
    <div id="bubbleChart"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you using `query.abort`? seems like that would abort the query, hence preventing `collectData` from being called. also, you should call `draw` from `collectData` -- not from `setTimeout` in `sendAndDraw`

Comment: if you submit your form, make sure you call a post method and return false after plot();

Comment: @WhiteHat The abort call was used in a code example provided by Google. Removing it doesn't seem to have any effect though. Regarding collectData, the problem is I have to call it for each spreadsheet, so I cannot call draw from there.

Comment: @kfa Why? (I'm new to Html as well). Where would I call the post method?

Comment: take a look at this and try with your former url : https://jsfiddle.net/pum77pf9/2/

Comment: @kfa Thanks! You only changed the form, right? I tried it, and now i get the `Data Table not defined` error once again.

Comment: @John_Isidore Yes but it's difficult to debug without the spreadsheet. Do you have any generic file we could get some input from ?

Comment: @kfa I skipped the part with multiple sheets and tried WhiteHat's suggestion. Now it's actually plotting something if I omit the `query.setQuery`, i.e. if I ask for the entire dataset. If I include it, I get the error I described. It seems as if my query string is not valid. Perhaps I need to put quotes around the names inside the `queryString` variable?

Comment: @John_Isidore well, I guess that's it, there's something wrong either with the query - which looks good though - or the way you use the response, the format may differ from what bubbleChart.draw() expect... try to console.log your various objects to debug

Comment: @kfa It seems like quotes were the issue. It appears to work now, but it's very slow. It takes like a second even for a very small datafile. Thanks a lot for your help! Now I just have to figure out how to solve the issue with several sheets...